# Getting " youâ€™ll " instead of "you're" in encoding?

Tags: php, encoding

I use PHP Simple DOM to grab a URL. When I print the urls content to screen, I get:

```
youâ€™ll
```

instead of:

```
you'll
```

If I run

```
$str = utf8_decode('youâ€™ll');
echo $str;
```

I get:

```
you?ll
```

I'm obviously not understanding the fundamentals of encoding. Can you someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the encoding to UTF-8 before do anything.
Start your php file with this:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
   mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
?>
```

and try to echo/print it without utf8_decode.

Note:
If you're using mysql (postgesql), use this too:

```
<?php 
   mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
   mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
?>
```

Edit: also, make sure you save your PHP file in UTF-8 (without BOM) format.

Comment: `SET NAMES`/`SET CHARACTER SET` is the thing that breaks `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Yes, people shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions anyway, but they *do* and the problem can be mitigated by using [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the document that you are outputting to be UTF-8 (assuming it actually *is* UTF-8) so the browser knows what to expect. You *could* convert the encoding, but if all you are doing is displaying it in the browser it would be better to leave the content as it is.

Add this line to your PHP before you output anything:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

...and add this meta tag as **the first** child element of your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```